# Как добавить свой интерактив к методу?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, extension, visual-studio-extensions, vsix

Пытаюсь поработать с VSIX. Суть расширения в том, чтобы анализировать код метода и перед его объявлением делать интерактивную ссылку на результат анализа. Также, как это сейчас сделано при поиске ссылок:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Подскажите, пожалуйста, в какую сторону копать хотя бы, чтобы вывести кликабельную ссылку перед методом? Или есть может примеры, которые можно посмотреть по этому вопросу?

Comment: Думаю, копать нужно в сторону Roslyn Analyzers.